# I need to pass file as form data via ajax and read from php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to pass file as  form data via ajax and read from php?

I am having a form which have file .It need to be sent to a php file .I dont want to use

form submit method.I am getting it..but image is not getting.

My code is as below:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post"  name="contact" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="contact_form">
<div class="input-group pull-left">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" name="stream_cotactname" id="stream_cotactname">
      </div>
       <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;">
        <span style="background:#000;"> <input type="file" placeholder="" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file"></span>
      </div>
```

**Now my javascript is :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var formdata = false;
(function () {    
var input = document.getElementById("uploaded_file");
        formdata = false;
    formdata = new FormData();
    input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;  
    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        file = this.files[i];
            if (formdata) {
         formdata.append("uploaded_file[]", file);
            }
    }
}, false);    
}());

function contact_mailsend()
{

         var app = 'sendmail.php';
$.ajax({
url: app,
async: false,
type:"POST",
data : "stream_cotactname="+name+"&file="+formdata,
dataType: "jsonp",
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    processData:false,
      jsonp: "jsoncallback",
success: function(html){
     alert("Thank you. We will be in touch with you");
     },
 error: function(){
 alert("error");
}
});
 }
 </script>
```

Here, Im not able to get form data in php if I do `print_r(file);`

I am able to get the name specified there.But not the form data(file)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `console.log(formdata);` before the `ajax` to see what's being sent. I'm not sure how you can pass a file that way. You can also make use of plugins such as _[this](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)_ or _[this](http://hayageek.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-jquery/)_.

Comment: I am using a cross domain, i am not familiar that I can do it with or not..please help

Comment: Hi,I withdraw my technique.I used another method to read data by decoding it into 64 bit data.Then pass to php.I have done it using file reader.ow I got the 64 bit data.But I need to get it in php.How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery form plugin to upload files using ajax as mentioned in below link.
[JQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload)

Comment: But I am using cross domain?